# How to open camera with a portrait orientation?

Tags: java, android, android-camera, orientation

My whole android camera app is in portrait mode, so when I open the camera I need it to automatically open in portrait mode. When I open the camera now the preview is sideways. How do I set the camera preview to open in portrait mode so the preview will look right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use this method from the [Android Developer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html#setDisplayOrientation(int)) documentation to rotate the camera preview.

> **public final void setDisplayOrientation (int degrees)**
>
> Set the clockwise rotation of preview display in degrees. This
>   affects the preview frames and the picture displayed after snapshot.
>   This method is useful for portrait mode applications. Note that
>   preview display of front-facing cameras is flipped horizontally before
>   the rotation, that is, the image is reflected along the central
>   vertical axis of the camera sensor. So the users can see themselves as
>   looking into a mirror.

```
private void setCameraDisplayOrientation(Activity activity, int cameraId,
        android.hardware.Camera camera) {
    android.hardware.Camera.CameraInfo info = new android.hardware.Camera.CameraInfo();
    android.hardware.Camera.getCameraInfo(cameraId, info);
    int rotation = activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay()
            .getRotation();

    int degrees = 0;
    switch (rotation) {
    case Surface.ROTATION_0:
        degrees = 0;
        break;
    case Surface.ROTATION_90:
        degrees = 90;
        break;
    case Surface.ROTATION_180:
        degrees = 180;
        break;
    case Surface.ROTATION_270:
        degrees = 270;
        break;
    }

    int result = 0;

    if (info.facing == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT) {
        result = (info.orientation + degrees) % 360;
        result = (360 - result) % 360; // compensate the mirror
    } else { // back-facing
        result = (info.orientation - degrees + 360) % 360;
    }
    camera.setDisplayOrientation(result);
}
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

It could because you haven't specified the screenRotation try:

```
 android:screenOrientation="portrait"
```

or try the following:

Add the orientation attribute in the manifest

```
android:screenOrientation=["unspecified" | "behind" |
                                     "landscape" | "portrait" |
                                     "reverseLandscape" | "reversePortrait" |
                                     "sensorLandscape" | "sensorPortrait" |
                                     "userLandscape" | "userPortrait" |
                                     "sensor" | "fullSensor" | "nosensor" |
                                     "user" | "fullUser" | "locked"]
So in your case it will be

<activity android:name=".yourCameractivity"
      ....
      android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
```